# appDelegate Reference

Tags: ios, macos, delegates

Is there a list of delegate methods for iOS/Mac apps?
I can't seem to find an Apple-sanctioned reference for the available methods.

What I'm looking for (ideally) is something like the [UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), but for (obviously) AppDelegates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tableView delegate you refer UITableViewDelegate, so, for application delegate [`UIApplicationDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is what you should refer.

Comment: @Patrick Perini, At first it was not obvious for me too. It took very very very very long for me to find it out :-(